# Spring Security "on behalf of" reactive implementation - client part

Tags: spring-security, reactive

I'm working on implementing "on behalf of" in SpringBoot. I have a working implementation. Now I'm trying to move it to a fully reactive stack.

What do I mean by saing - moving to fully reactive stack?

I want to replace:

@EnableWebSecurity, ClientRegistrationRepository, OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager, ...

Using their reactive implementation, to be consistent with resource server part of my application.

The problem I ran into is:
`public Mono<Data> getDataD(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("client_id") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient)`

**authorizedClient** is null, when my base implementation works ok.

```
    @GetMapping("/data-a/d")
    public Mono<Data> getDataD(@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("client_id") OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient) {
        Mono<Data> data = Mono.just(new Data("OBO POC D", "POC D"));
        Mono<DataB> dataB = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8081/data-b/b")
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(DataB.class);

        Mono<Data> zippedData = data.zipWith(dataB, (a, b) -> a.setData(b));
        return zippedData;
    }
```

I tried to follow a different path:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/reactive/oauth2/client/authorization-grants.html#oauth2Client-jwt-bearer-grant

It looks promising, because this time an authorization request is being sent, but the AD claims that the request does not contain the "requested_token_use" parameter, which is required. I don't know how to extend the request with additional parameters – this feature is only mentioned in documentation.

```
    @GetMapping("/data-a/c")
    public Mono<Data> getDataC(JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthentication, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        Mono<Data> data = Mono.just(new Data("OBO POC A", "POC C"));

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("obo_rs_a-obo_rs_b")
                .principal(jwtAuthentication)
                //.attribute("requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of")
                .build();

        return this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
                .map(c -> {
                    OAuth2AccessToken token = c.getAccessToken();
                    System.out.println("SCOPES: "  + token.getScopes());
                    return token;})
                .zipWith(data, (a,b) -> b);
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After several experiments, I've found working solution eventually.

```
    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        WebClientReactiveJwtBearerTokenResponseClient jwtBearerTokenResponseClient = new WebClientReactiveJwtBearerTokenResponseClient();
        jwtBearerTokenResponseClient.setParametersConverter(r -> {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            parameters.add(OAuth2ParameterNames.GRANT_TYPE, r.getGrantType().getValue());
            parameters.add("requested_token_use", "on_behalf_of");
            return parameters;
        });
...
```

```
    @GetMapping("/data-a/c")
    public Mono<Data> getDataC(JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuthentication) {
        Mono<Data> data = Mono.just(new Data("OBO POC A", "POC A calls B - the hard way :-)"));

        OAuth2AuthorizeRequest authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest.withClientRegistrationId("obo_rs_a-obo_rs_b")
                .principal(jwtAuthentication)
                .build();

        Mono<DataB> dataB =  this.authorizedClientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)
                .flatMap(c -> webClient.get()
                        .uri("http://localhost:8081/data-b/b")
                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + c.getAccessToken().getTokenValue())
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(DataB.class));
        Mono<Data> zippedData = data.zipWith(dataB, (a, b) -> a.setData(b));
        return zippedData;
    }
```

I'm still not sure if this implementation is correct.